# Repeating an If command within an If command

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Lets say I have a sensor that reads movement. If it detects movement, then it does something. After doing said thing, the sensor checks again for movement. If it doesn't detect any movement, then it moves on to the next command. If it **still** detects movement, then it continues to check for movement until it no longer detects any movement. How do I repeat an if command, **within** an if command

```
if(movement = yes){
 statement;
 delay;
 }if(movement still equals yes){
  repeat and check again until you get the other result
 }if(movement = no){
  statement;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at while() loop [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/while/), make it part of the loop() function.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino already has a loop `void loop ()` so inside the loop you must include your if statements only once and it will keep working.

```
bool detection;
void loop () {
  if ( detection == true ) 
  {
    statement;
  }else
  {
    the othe statement;
  }
}
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.